# Split lines in .txt file in Python

Tags: python

I have a .txt file:

```
My
name is
Richard
```

And I want to get something like `['My', 'name is', 'Richard']`.

I tried

```
file = open("Text.txt")
strings = file.read()
strings = strings.split()
print(strings)
```

But it gives me `['My', 'name', 'is', 'Richard']`. So how can I get it line by line?

Comment: `file.readlines()` reads file line by line, and do not use `file` as a variable name, its a predefined name.

Comment: @ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ`file` was a built-in type name in Python 2, but it no longer exists in Python 3.

Comment: @PM2Ring , it would still be good programming practice to avoid reserved words, current and deprecated.

Comment: @DavidCulbreth I tend to agree, although I know several coders who only use Python 3 these days who like to use `file` for their own variables. BTW, it was never a reserved word like `for`, `while`, etc; it's a syntax error to use a reserved word as a variable name.

Answer (score 3):

`split()` splits by any whitespace. Use this:

```
file = open("text.txt")
strings = [line.strip() for line in file]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There's an integrated function for this called `readlines()`. There is a [Tutorials Point article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readlines.htm) about it, and it's in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) as well.

You would use it like so.

```
with open('path/to/my/file') as myFile:
    for line in myFile.readlines():
        print line
```

And straight from the [documentation themselves](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects), from at least Python 3.5 to 3.7,

> If you want to read all the lines of a file in a list you can also use `list(f)` or `f.readlines()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
strings = strings.splitlines()
```

instead of

```
strings = strings.split()
```

The `splitlines` method splits a string by newline characters.